# After refreshing angular application in browser: django response

Tags: python, django, angular, url-routing, django-urls

I´m currently working on an application: Django backend and angular frontend. Everything works fine, but after refreshing one page in the browser I don´t get the angular response anymore. But what I get is a successful answer from my Django server (HTTPResponse: 200).

My Django urls.py is as followed:

```
from django.urls import path
from quickstart import views

# Wire up our API using automatic URL routing.
# Additionally, we include login URLs for the browsable API.
urlpatterns = [
    path('images/', views.ImageList.as_view()),
    path('images/<str:id>/', views.Image.as_view()),
    path('images/<str:id>/explanations', views.Explanation.as_view())
]
```

My app-routing.modules.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'home', component: MainComponent},
  {path: 'images', component: ImageComponent, children: [
    {
      path:':id', component: ImageDetailComponent
    }
  ]},
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'},
  
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(
    routes
  )],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular production build  is served as a static file. it makes the api request to the backend server for the CRUD operations.

what you need to do is serve the static files in angular dist(most probably the index.html file in the dist folder) folder.

using some sort of routing in django *(suggestion have a prefix for the API or web app for django to know what are you asking for. look at [this](https://medium.com/swlh/django-angular-4-a-powerful-web-application-60b6fb39ef34))*

or have a standalone service hosted some where to serve Angular site(have a look at [this](https://sidhu-dreamer.medium.com/deploy-angular-app-in-node-server-express-static-rest-api-method-in-the-same-port-2c8b5a39ebce)) and let angular handle the routing.